# BigInteger pow function not being calculated in Paillier Encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, biginteger, paillier

Here is my Paillier class:

```
public class Paillier {
    private static BigInteger Nv;
    private static BigInteger Nc;
    private static BigInteger b;
    private static BigInteger p;
    private static BigInteger q;
    private static BigInteger n;
    private static BigInteger nsquared;
    private static BigInteger lambda;
    private static BigInteger g;
    private static BigInteger mu;

    public Paillier(BigInteger cNv, BigInteger cNc, BigInteger cb, BigInteger cp, BigInteger cq) {
        this.Nv = cNv;
        this.Nc = cNc;
        this.b = cb;
        this.p = cp;
        this.q = cq;

        keyGeneration();
    }

    public static BigInteger getn() {
        return n;
    }

public static void keyGeneration() {
    n = p.multiply(q);
    nsquared = n.multiply(n);

    lambda = carmichaelFunction();

    g = new BigInteger("1578485334874745");
    BigInteger gModPow = LFunction(g.modPow(lambda, nsquared));

    mu = gModPow.modInverse(n);

    /**System.out.print("Encryption key: (" + n + ", " + g + ") \n");
     System.out.print("Decryption key: (" + lambda + ", " + mu + ") \n");**/
}

public static BigInteger carmichaelFunction() {
    BigInteger product = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    BigInteger lamb = product.divide(p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));

    return lamb;
}

public static BigInteger LFunction(BigInteger u) {
    BigInteger L = u.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n);

    return L;
}

public BigInteger encryption(int[] votes) {
    BigInteger m = BigInteger.ZERO;

    for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i.compareTo(Nc) == -1; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        if (votes[i.intValue()] == 1)
            m = m.add(b.pow(i.intValue()));
    }

    Log.d("MESSAGE","Message to be encrypted "+ m);
    Log.d("n ", n.toString());
    Log.d("nsquared ", nsquared.toString());

    BigInteger r = randomZStarN();
    Log.d("RandomZStarN ", r.toString());

    BigInteger gmi = g.pow(m.intValue());
    Log.d("gmi ", gmi.toString());
    BigInteger rin = r.pow(n.intValue());
    Log.d("rin ", rin.toString());
    BigInteger gMr = gmi.multiply(rin);
    Log.d("gMr ", gMr.toString());
    BigInteger c = gMr.mod(nsquared);
    Log.d("Ciphertext ", c.toString());

    return c;
}

public static BigInteger randomZStarN() {
    BigInteger r;

    do {
        r = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), new Random());
    } while (r.compareTo(n) >= 0 || r.gcd(n).intValue() != 1);

    return r;
}
}
```

In the encryption method, the variable *rin* is not being calculated and logged and so are the variables after it. The Android application then stops responding. I am assuming it's because *c* is returning a null value.

The output is as follows and the log d doesn't display the value of *rin*:

```
01-15 11:03:22.593 3468-3468/com.example.oct30th D/MESSAGE: Message to be encrypted 1
01-15 11:03:22.593 3468-3468/com.example.oct30th D/n: 1291588321
01-15 11:03:22.593 3468-3468/com.example.oct30th D/nsquared: 1668200390943599041
01-15 11:03:22.594 3468-3468/com.example.oct30th D/RandomZStarN: 75325222
01-15 11:03:22.594 3468-3468/com.example.oct30th D/gmi: 1578485334874745
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: It doesn't continue because `75325222.pow(1291588321)` takes forever to calculate.

Comment: The result of that calculation is a number with more than 10 **billion** digits. Approx: `1.21e10173764252`

Comment: @Andreas Any solution to this problem?

Comment: @user8777308: check your algorithm. It is very unlikely that such a huuuuge number is correct or required. It would make encryption almost impossible.

Comment: FWIW, on my system, `75325222.pow(1291588)` took approx. **19 seconds**. But `75325222.pow(12915880)` (10 x the exponent) took **527 seconds**. The numbers get larger and larger, which makes multiplying them slower and slower (even when they use Karatsuba or Toom-Cook algorithms). You can imagine that `75325222.pow(1291588321)` might take ages to complete and could also run out of memory, on many systems (the calculation requires several similarly large numbers to be in memory at the same time).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis What do you suggest since this calculation needs to be excuted with an Android app ? Thank you.

Comment: @user8777308: I already said what I would suggest:check your algorithm. It is very unlikely that it is correct, if it must calculate such huge values. Does it perhaps need modPow instead? That is **much** faster, as it keeps the values below the modulus, so no extremely big values have to be multiplied.